# send data grid view data in an e-mail using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, datagridview

i'm trying to send a datagridview (or just the data in the grid) to an e-mail but i only receive a blank e-mail when it's sent, anyone got any ideas how to fix it?
The code im using is this:

```
Try
        SMTP.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        SMTP.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("[e-mail address im sending from]", "[password for that e-mail]")

        SMTP.Port = 25
        SMTP.EnableSsl = True
        mail = New MailMessage
        mail.From = New MailAddress("[e-mail im sending from]")
        mail.To.Add(UserEmail.Text)
        mail.Body = DataTab.ToString
        mail.Subject = "Biology quiz Highscores"
        SMTP.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        SMTP.Send(mail)
        MsgBox("E-mail sent to: " & UserEmail.Text & "")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to send e-mail. Please try again later.")
    End Try
```

im getting the data from a 2003 access database using mydataadpter sql statement, the data table variable is called datatab.

Comment: `or just the data in the grid` this would be the wiser choice

Comment: any ideas how to do this? whenever i try to add just the data table it comes up with an error saying it can't convert to a string but when i put .tostring it just sends a blank e-mail

Comment: send the *data in* the datatable, objects like a DataGridView, DataTable or any sort of Adapter wont email easily or be readable on the other end without a helper app

Comment: you got an example of the code i could use? because it wont allow me to just send the dataset without converting it to a string but then i just get "system.data.dataset" in the e-mail if i do .tostring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object.ToString(), unless overridden, is identical to calling Object.GetType().ToString().

You want to show the data in the data table. You could do something like this:

```
Private Sub YourSubWhereYouSendEmail()
    '...

    Try
        Using smtp = New SmtpClient() With {
                                             .UseDefaultCredentials = False,
                                             .Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("[e-mail address im sending from]", "[password for that e-mail]"),
                                             .Port = 25,
                                             .EnableSsl = True,
                                             .DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
                                           }

            smtp.Send(New MailMessage("[e-mail im sending from]"), UserEmail.Text, "Biology quiz Highscores", DataTableToCSVString(DataTab)))
        End Using
        MsgBox("E-mail sent to: " & UserEmail.Text & "")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to send e-mail. Please try again later.")
    End Try

    '...
End Sub

Private Function DataTableToCSVString(table As DataTable) As String
    With New Text.StringBuilder
        Dim once = False

        'headers
        For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
            If once = False Then
                once = True
            Else
                .Append(",")
            End If
            .Append(col.ColumnName)
        Next

        .AppendLine()

        'rows
        For Each s In table.Select.Select(Function(row) String.Join(",", row.ItemArray))
            .AppendLine(s)
        Next

        Return .ToString
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Cheers, works perfectly. Only thing I had to change was had to do system.text.string builder